# Pandas Drop Rows when Exactly Matching Items from a List

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to drop rows in a pandas dataframe on an exact match. My code nearly works, but it currently drops rows which match partially (which I don't want).

The code below will drop the name 'Krish' from the dataframe because it partially matches to 'kris'.

```
import pandas as pd

# list of strings to drop in an exact match
drop_list = ["nick", "kris"]

# initialize data of lists.
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df[~df['Name'].str.contains("|".join(drop_list))]

# print dataframe.
print(df)
```

**Current Output:**

```
   Name  Age
0   Tom   20
3  jack   18
```

**Desired Output:**

```
    Name  Age
0    Tom   20
2  krish   19
3   jack   18
```

Comment: [Series.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) -> `df = df[~df['Name'].isin(drop_list)]`

Answer (score 3):

Use `isin`:

```
df = df[~df['Name'].isin(drop_list)]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    Name  Age
0    Tom   20
2  krish   19
3   jack   18
```